# What is the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, object, twitter, tweepy

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I am trying to enter a time in which tells the twitter API how long to stream for. I am getting the error and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "streamobjecttest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import StatusStream
  File "/Users/yaminhimani/Desktop/tweetybird/StatusStream.py", line 68, in <module>
    twitterStream = Stream(auth=auth, listener=StatusStream(),tweet_mode='extended')
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

stream .py file

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import time
import Tweet
import DatabaseInteractor 
import twitter_credentials




class StatusStream(StreamListener):


    def __init__(self, timeLimit):
      self.start_time = time.time()
      self.timeLimit = timeLimit
      super(StatusStream, self).__init__(timeLimit)


    def on_status(self, status):


   if (time.time()- self.start_time < self.timeLimit):
       print(status.text)



def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return False



auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.API_KEY,twitter_credentials.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN,twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitterStream = Stream(auth=auth, listener=StatusStream(),tweet_mode='extended')
twitterStream.filter(track=["plumber","visa","bathtub"])
```

Different .py file

```
import StatusStream
import Tweet




stream= StatusStream.StatusStream(20)
```

Comment: Probably: `super(StatusStream, self).__init__(timeLimit)`.

Comment: Do: `super(StatusStream, self).__init__(timeLimit)`

Comment: I just updated my question with new information

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class StatusStream(StreamListener):


     def __init__(self, timeLimit):
          self.start_time = time.time()
          self.timeLimit = timeLimit
          super().__init__(timeLimit)
```

This will work in Python 3. Your syntax works for Python 2. Also, IDK if StreamListener initializes timeLimit, so you may or may not need to pass timeLimit in the init.

Comment: I updated my post. I am still having trouble with this issue.